# unable to add an item to list property

Tags: c#, list, properties, visual-studio-2013

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                ListDemo _list = new ListDemo();
                _list.Str.Add("string1");
                _list.Str.Add("string2");
                _list.Str.Add("string3");
                foreach (string item in _list.Str)
                {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
class ListDemo
{
    string[] _str = new string[3];
    public List<string> Str
    {
        get
        {
            return _str.ToList();
        }
        set
        {
            _str = value.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add an new item to the list. Above I provided the sample code but I am unable to add an item to the list.

Please help me in solving the issue.

Thanks,
Phani.

Comment: Why don't you use a `List<string>` in the first place instead of an array? `_str.ToList()` return always a new list, so `_list.Str.Add("string1")` is not added to the array (which is also not possible since an array is fixed length).

Answer (score 0):

_str.ToList() returns new object of List type. But this object doesn't correspond to _str, is only contains same data. I'd suggest to use List instead of string[] for _str, thought you already have performance leak in your property. Then your property will work correctly

Comment: _"object doesn't correspond to _str, is only contains same methods"_ Not quite correct, an array and a list do not have the same methods. They are different types and diffferent objects. OP does not modify the array or assign a different array. That's why it is not changed.

Comment: @TimSchmelter My misprint, meant data, not methods. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to keep the current ListDemo class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ListDemo _list = new ListDemo();               //Declare an instance of the ListDemo class.

        List<string> newStrList = new List<string>();  //Declare a new List<string>.
        newStrList.Add("string1");                     //Add strings like this.
        newStrList.Add("string2");
        newStrList.Add("string3");

        _list.Str = newStrList;                        //Add the entire collection to the ListDemo at once, like this.

        foreach (string item in _list.Str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class ListDemo
{
    string[] _str = new string[3];
    public List<string> Str
    {
        get
        {
            return _str.ToList();
        }
        set
        {
            _str = value.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Otherwise, rather just use:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         List<string> _list = new List<string>(); //Declare an empty list like this.
        _list.Add("string1");                     //Add a string to it like this.
        _list.Add("string2");
        string valueOfString3 = "string3";
        _list.Add(valueOfString3);                //Or like this.

        foreach (string item in _list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If you then want it as an array, you can just say:

```
string[] arrayOfList = _list.toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         ListDemo _list = new ListDemo();

        List<String> Str=new List<String>();
        Str.Add("string1");
        Str.Add("string2");
        Str.Add("string3");

        _list.Str=Str;

        foreach (string item in _list.Str)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class ListDemo
{
    string[] _str = new string[3];
    public List<string> Str
    {
        get
        {
            return _str.ToList();
        }
        set
        {
            _str = value.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```